# Differences between wpf xaml/programming and metro xaml/programming

Tags: wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have some background with windows presentation foundation and now I am trying to move to metro.

I have some experience with wpf with custom markup extensions, resource dictionaries, various template types, various resource types such as dynamic or static, type converters, various existing markup extensions in xaml such as binding or ancestral binding and dependency properties in general.

Are there some key differences between metro and wpf in terms of programming related to what I mentioned above?

Comment: are you talking abt windows rt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you will run into various nuance differences it will take some time to get used to. If for example, you're coming from more of a Silverlight background, you may find it a bit easier of a transition than if you've been strictly WPF. However most of the time the concepts will remain the same and the differences will be trivial. Like for example more reliance on `VisualStateManager` rather than `Style Triggers`, or newly introduced available controls at your disposal like `VariableSizeWrapGrid` and newly available gesture functionality targeted more towards the touch enabled devices, etc, etc...

Howevever this topic can be found covered in length and in detail with a quick trip to your favorite search engine results, so I wouldn't be surprised if you find your question down-voted.

Comment: WinRT XAML is laughable compared to WPF XAML. No custom markupextensions, no RelativeSource, no Style Setter binding. it sucks. It takes away all the goodness of WPF and forces you to go back to winforms-type horrible code-behind type workaround hacks

Comment: Haha much love for ya buddy @HighCore, and hey, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758289.aspx